# GitLab API to access all details related to open merge requests using Python

Tags: python, api, gitlab

GitLab API to access all details related to open merge requests using Python.

I am trying to make a UI similar to shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/index.html#mergerequest

Simple demo hitting the GraphQL API directly:

```py
import requests

cursor = None
while True:
    response = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/api/graphql",
                             json={
                                 "query": """
query ($projectId: ID!, $cursor: String) {
  project(fullPath: $projectId) {
    mergeRequests(state: opened, after: $cursor) {
      nodes {
        approved
        author {
          name
        }
        createdAt
        id
        sourceBranch
        title
        updatedAt
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
}""",
                                 "variables": {
                                     "projectId": "gitlab-org/gitlab",
                                     "cursor": cursor
                                 }
                             })
    response.raise_for_status()
    response = response.json()
    if "errors" in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response["errors"])
    for merge_request in response["data"]["project"]["mergeRequests"]["nodes"]:
        print(merge_request)
    cursor = response["data"]["project"]["mergeRequests"]["pageInfo"][
        "endCursor"]
    if cursor is None:
        break
```

Replace the raw use of `requests` with whichever GraphQL client library you choose. Replace `gitlab.com` and `gitlab-org/gitlab` with the GitLab instance and project you are using. Test the query and read interactive documentation at https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer (again, replacing `gitlab.com` with the appropriate instance; query variables can be dragged up from below the query input area).